# Intersection points in Fortune's algoritm for computing Voronoi diagram

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry, voronoi

I am finding it very difficult to follow fortune's algorithm, I have gone through all the resources available on the net and fairly understood the theory behind it. But when I am implementing it on my own the little details which were left out in the sources have been a real pain for me. The intersection points, which I understood are the center of a circle with two given points on it and a horizontal tangent with equation y = c but working through the equations I am unable to get the co-ordinates of the center(the intersection point). Can someone please help me on how to find the co-ordinates of the intersection points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are asking about?

```
INPUT:
two given points:
[x1, y1]
[x2, y2]
and a real number: 
c
where y = c is a horizontal line 

CALCULATION of the coordinates of the centre of the circle
that passes through the two given points [x1, y1] and [x2, y2] 
and is tangent to the horizontal line y = c:

    k = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)
    x_P = x1 + k * (c - y1)
    t = sqrt((x_P - x1)^2 + (c - y1)^2) * math.sqrt((x_P - x2)^2 + (c - y2)^2)
    t = sqrt(t)
    x_center = x_P - t * k / abs(k)
    y_center = (y1 + y2) / 2  - k * (x_center - (x1 + x2)/2)
```

**Geometric Construction.** Let us have two points `A = [x1, y1]` and `B = [x2, y2]` and let `y = c` bet he horizontal line, where `y1 < c` and `y2 < c`. We are looking for the center `O = [x_center, y_center]` of the circle `C` that passes through the points `A` and `B` and is tangent to the line `y = c`.

1. Write the equation of the line `AB` that passes through the points `A` and `B`. This allows us to find the coordinates of the intersection point `P = [x_P, y_P]` between the lines `AB` and `y = c`. Without loss of generality, assume that point `B` is between points `A` and `P`.
2. Our next goal is to find the coordinates of the point `T` at which the circle `C` is tangent to the line `y = c`. To do that, we will first find be the distance `t = PT` between the points `P` and `T`. After that, we simply have to move distance `t` from the point `P` along the line `y = c`, which means we find the `x` coordinate `x_T` of `T` as either `x_T = x_P - t` or `x_T = x_P + t` (there are two solutions). The `y` coordinate of `T` is `y_T = c`.
3. Consider the two triangles `PAT` and `PTB`. They share a common angle `angle TPA = angle BPT`. Furthermore, because `y = c` is tangent to the circle `C` circumscribed around the triangle `ABT`, we can deduce that `angle PTA = angle PBT`. Therefore triangles `PAT` and `PTB` are similar.
4. The similarity between `PAT` and `PTB` yields the similarity identity `PT / PA = PB / PT` which can be rewritten as `t^2 = PT^2 = PA * PB`. Thus, we can find that `t = sqrt(PA * PB)` (this is what `t` is in the code).
5. Finally, we find that `x_T = x_P - t` or `x_T = x_P + t`, whichever is closer to the segment `AB`. The center `O` of the circle `C` is the intersection of the vertical line `x = x_T` and the orthogonal bisector of segment `AB` (the line through the midpoint of `AB` and perpendicular to `AB`)

*Remark:* There is a degenerate case when the line `AB` is parallel to the line `y = c`. Then the picture is more symmetric and one can use a slightly different method, which I have included in the code below

Test code in python:

```py
import numpy as np
import math


def find_center(A, B, c):
    x1 = A[0]
    y1 = A[1]
    x2 = B[0]
    y2 = B[1]
    if abs(y1 - y2) < 1e-7:
        radius = ((2*c - y1 - y2)**2 + (x2 - x1)**2) / (8*(c - y1))
        x_center = (x1 + x2) / 2
        y_center = c - radius 
    else:
        k = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)
        x_P = x1 + k * (c - y1)
        t = math.sqrt((x_P - x1)**2 + (c - y1)**2) * math.sqrt((x_P - x2)**2 + (c - y2)**2)
        t = math.sqrt(t)
        x_center = x_P - t * k / abs(k)
        y_center = (y1 + y2) / 2  - k * (x_center - (x1 + x2)/2)     
    return np.array([x_center, y_center])

A = np.array([0, 0])
B = np.array([3, 1.5])
c = 5

O = find_center(A, B, c)

print('print the distances between the calculated center and the two points and the horizontal line: ')
print((np.linalg.norm(A - O), np.linalg.norm(B - O),  c - O[1]))
```

**Edit.** Here is another method, which also takes care of the degenerate case when `y1 = y2`, i.e. the points `A` and `B` form a line parallel to `y = c`.

**Construction.** All points from the plane that are at an equal distance from the line `y = c` and the point `A = [x1, y1]` form a parabola with directrix `y = c` and focus `A`. So simply write the equation of this parabola:

```
distance(X, A)^2 = distance(X, {y=c})^2

or as a quadratic equation:

(x - x1)^2  +  (y - y1)^2 = (c - y)^2

which simplifies to 

y = ( x^2 - 2*x1* x + x1^2 + y1^2 - c^2 ) / (y1 - c)
```

The same applies to point `B = [x2, y2]` and line `y = c`, where the equation of the parabola with focus `B` and directrix `a = c` is

```
y = ( x^2 - 2*x2* x + x2^2 + y2^2 - c^2 ) / (y2 - c)
```

Therefore, the points that are at equal distance from `A`, `B` and `y = c` should be the two intersection points of the two parabolas. In terms of equations, you simply have to solve the equation

```
 ( x^2 - 2*x1* x + x1^2 + y1^2 - c^2 ) / (y1 - c) =  ( x^2 - 2*x2* x + x2^2 + y2^2 - c^2 ) / (y2 - c)
```

for the unknown `x` coordinate of `O`. Then the `y` coordinate is found by plugging the solution in one of the parabola equations above.

Here is some python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

def sqe(a):
    def sqe(a):
    if abs(a[0]) < 1e-7:
        return - a[2] / a[1], - a[2] / a[1]
    D = math.sqrt(a[1]**2 - 4*a[0]*a[2])
    return ( - a[1] - D ) /(2*a[0]), ( - a[1] + D ) / (2*a[0])

def find_center(A, B, c):
    x1 = A[0]
    y1 = A[1]
    x2 = B[0]
    y2 = B[1]     
    a1 = np.array([1, -2*x1, x1**2 + y1**2 - c**2])
    a2 = np.array([1, -2*x2, x2**2 + y2**2 - c**2])
    x_center = sqe((y1-c)*a2 - (y2-c)*a1)[1]
    y_center = (a1[0]*x_center**2 + a1[1]*x_center + a1[2])  / (2*y1-2*c)      
    return np.array([x_center, y_center])

A = np.array([0, 0])
B = np.array([3, 0.5])
c = 5

O = find_center(A, B, c)
print('print the distances between the calculated center and the two points and the horizontal line: ')
print((np.linalg.norm(A - O), np.linalg.norm(B - O),  c - O[1]))
```

Comment: what is t in this?

Comment: @sam I added more to my answer.

Comment: @sam I was a bit sloppy in developing the first method. I did not bother to calculate separately the degenerate case when `y1 = y2`, i.e. when the segment `AB` is parallel to the line `y = c`. That is why I included the second one. If you really need this extra calculation for the case `y1 = y2`, let me know I can add it. If  the answer is enough as is, then I will just leave it like that.